# Excel read in a Matlab function

Tags: excel, matlab, function

I defined a function calculating the corresponding electron density at the given temperature based on the data given by database in my excel file. The problem is that, every time this function is called, it opens the excel file, which is really time-consuming. I don't want to put the whole database as input of this function, and I do not want to define `data` as global, does anyone know how can I just read this excel file ones for all temperatures being input?

```
function [electron density] = electrondensity(temperature)
data=xlsread('D:\Matlabcode\partitionfunctions.xlsx',2,'A2:D5');
......
end
```

Comment: Have a separate function to read your data from the excel file and [save the subset you want to a *.mat file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) that you can [load](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) into your main function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a persistent variable:

```
function [electron density] = electrondensity(temperature)
persistent data;
if isempty(data)
    disp('calling xlsread')
    data=xlsread('D:\Matlabcode\partitionfunctions.xlsx',2,'A2:D5');
end
```

That way the first time you call the function the variable is created, initialized to empty matrix, and xlsread is called. The next times you call the function the variable is retrieved and xlsread is not called.

To 'clear' the value of the persistent variable (that will not appear in variable workspace) use `clear electrondensity`.

Similarly you could also use a global variable.